# Connection refused when trying to create a connection

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, apache

We are using `django` to call APIs (`ubuntu` server) that are on `172.20.44.148`.

Our code is the following:

```
import socket
socket.create_connection(('172.20.44.148', 8080), timeout=2)
```

However, the connection refused.

This is the error we got from `apache`:

```
[root@xxx ~]# python /home/something.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/something.py", line 3, in <module>
    socket.create_connection(('172.20.44.148', 8080), timeout=2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

We also tried to ping `172.20.44.148` and we got a response.

Any ideas?

Comment: `telnet 172.20.44.148 8080` can tell you if 8080 port is open for you.

Comment: Where is Apache in this situation?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth We will try it. In care the port 8080 is closed, how do we open it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Apache for `django` app is on the django server: `172.20.44.148`.

Comment: You're being confusing. What is the "django app" here? You say you are *using Django to call APIs", but your calling code appears to be running standalone from the command line. Do you mean "using Python to call a Django app running behind Apache"? Also, please show the actual Apache configuration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm sorry. The django app, is a website. Using the 'view' of django app, we call the script we have here, in order to connect to another virtual machine locally to call APIs to handle the website's data (store/select from a database).

Comment: OK, fine. But as I say, you need to show the Apache configuration. Is your API actually running on that IP and port? Are you sure? Does it work from the browser?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, we are sure. We tested in on a single machine (laptop) firstly. We haven't checked it from browser on the virtual machine yet.

Comment: Once again, you need to show the Apache configuration. Why is it serving on port 8080, rather than port 80?